# BreadthFirstScan and DepthFirstScan

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

Recently, I have been playing with the functions `BreadthFirstScan` and `DepthFirstScan`. I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between the following two events that are mentioned in documentation to those functions.

- Events that provide access to **vertex visits**
- Events that provide access to **vertex discovery**

I would be very grateful if anyone would enlighten me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Discovery" means that the vertex is seen, and registered for later processing.

"Visiting" means processing a vertex. This is a long process which includes processing its neighbours as well. Thus, there are two events: one is triggered when processing starts and one when processing finishes.

In depth-first search, processing a vertex means:

- Fire `Previsit` event.
- Look at who its (out-)neighbours are. This is "discovery". Different events can fire depending on whether these neighbours have been seen before.
- Add those neighbours which have not yet been seen to a processing queue.
- Process each neighbour in turn from the queue.
- One all its neighbours have been processed, fire the `Postvisit` event.

An example:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 4 -> 6},
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
DepthFirstScan[
 g, 1,
 {"DiscoverVertex" -> (Echo[Row[{#1, " from ", #2}], "discover"] &),
  "UnvisitedVertex" -> (Echo[Row[{#1, " from ", #2}], "unvisited"] &),
  "VisitedVertex" -> (Echo[Row[{#1, " from ", #2}], "visited"] &), (* won't fire for this graph because there are no cycles *)
  "PrevisitVertex" -> (Echo[#, "previsit"] &),
  "PostvisitVertex" -> (Echo[#, "postvisit"] &)}
 ]
```

[image]

Maybe with these names it's easier to understand:

```
DepthFirstScan[
 g, 1,
 {"DiscoverVertex" -> (Echo[Row[{#1, " from ", #2}], "see unknown vertex"] &),
  "UnvisitedVertex" -> (Echo[Row[{#1, " from ", #2}], "see known unprocessed vertex"] &),
  "VisitedVertex" -> (Echo[Row[{#1, " from ", #2}], "see known processed vertex"] &), (* won't fire for this graph because there are no cycles *)
  "PrevisitVertex" -> (Echo[#, "start processing"] &),
  "PostvisitVertex" -> (Echo[#, "done with"] &)}
 ]
```